# Control bound to property value doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm having a bit of a problem with WPF property binding. First the code.

C#

```
public partial class WPFTextBox: UserControl
{
    private bool _bold;
    public bool Bold
    {
        get { return _bold; }
        set
        {
            _bold = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Bold");
        }
    }

    private bool _selectionChanged;

    public WPFTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Bold = true;  // <--- This works, the checkbox will be checked
        _selectionChanged = false;
     }

     private void txtDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         var selection = txtDetails.Selection;
         _selectionChanged = true;
         Bold = selection.FontWeight() == FontWeights.Bold; 
         // ^-- This doesn't work It will trigger everything, but the checkbox won't
         // change value. FontWeight() is an extension I wrote
         _selectionChanged = false;
     }

     private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
     {
         if(_selectionChanged)
            return; // If the change was brought from the user moving the
                    // cursor in the textbox, don't change the textbox.
         TextRange range = txtDetails.Selection;
         switch(name)
         {
             case "Bold":
                 // change selection to bold, like I mentioned I does work
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }
}
```

XAML

```
<RichTextBox Name="txtDetails" SelectionChanged="txtDetails_SelectionChanged"/>

<CheckBox Name="chkBold" Content="Bold" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bold}"/>
```

I'm creating a textbox with format options. The binding works in the constructor, but not in the selection changed event. I've tried adding a lot of options to the binding such as `Mode=TwoWay` and different property changed triggers.

The reason I'm using the `_selectionChanged` bool is because if I don't check for that, if I have a word was different formatting such as he**llo** and I click on it, it will change the formatting for all of the word to either bold or not. I think maybe it's because I'm handling it in selection changed event, but then I'm not sure where else I could change property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), you can just grab the INPC part.

```
set
{
    _bold = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("Bold");
     NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I'm using .Net 4.0. I don't have support for `[CallerMemberName]`. It does seem like I can install workarounds, but this is meant to be used by other people and not just my self. We are planning on upgrading some time soon, but until then... .Net 4.0 it is. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you can actually omit [CallerMemberName] sugar and it will work. NotifyPropertyChanged("Bold").

Comment: Yep, it worked. Would you know why Extended WPF Toolkit controls aren't updating like the checkbox?

Comment: Nevermind, I was being a dumb-dumb. Forgot to make the `propertyName` I was passing the same as the name of the property...

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

and implement `PropertyChangedEventHandler`

```
public class WPFTextBox: UserControl,System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {            
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

And call `OnPropertyChanged` in the setter of your property

Comment: Does binding work on controls from the Extended WPF Toolkit? I got it to work on my checkboxes, but while binding seems does seem to trigger on the integerupdown, I can't seem update the value in the control.

Comment: Binding works on both Dependency and CLR properties of the control,but for CLR property the setter's not actually involved in change notification so you need to check whether that property is dependency property or not.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** event also.
2.Yes binding work on controls from the Extended WPF Toolkit.
 **IsChecked="{xcd:Path=Bold}"**